# Can a map $\phi$ be defined such that $\phi\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)f''\left(x\right)}{f'\left(x\right)^{2}}\right)=f\left(x\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

As per the title, does a mapping $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ exist such that

$$\phi\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)f''\left(x\right)}{f'\left(x\right)^{2}}\right)=f\left(x\right)\text{?}$$

For clarification, if we defined $H(f'(x))=f(x)$, then $H$ is the operator $\int_0^x f'(s)ds=f(x)$. Note that this is equivalent to solving the second-order nonlinear ODE for $f(x)$

$$\frac{f\left(x\right)f''\left(x\right)}{f'\left(x\right)^{2}}=g(x).$$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A little nitpick -- it seems like $\phi$ is more naturally defined as eating functions and returning functions (like your $H$ is really doing), rather than eating numbers and returning numbers.

Comment: Thanks, so is it more naturally defined as an operator rather than a map (i.e. $H$)?

Comment: $H$ is not a mapping, it is an operator. Do you want $\phi$ a mapping or an operator?

Comment: Also, $H(f’)=f(x)-f(0),$ as defined by the integral. There is no $H$ that works for all $f.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I think that the framing in terms of a mapping/operator  $\phi$ is a little broken, but for suitable $f, g$, we can solve the differential equation.

Put $h(x) = f(x)/f'(x)$. Then
$$
h'(x) = \frac{-f'(x)^2 + f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} =  \frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} - 1.
$$
So the differential equation is then
$$
h'(x) + 1 = g(x) 
$$
which we can solve for $h$ given an antiderivative for $g - 1$. We can recover $f$ from $h$ using $h(x) = \frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx} \log(f(x))}$.